# Is Xamarin Studio a good option to create C# apps in MAC?

Tags: xamarin

Sorry for my ignorance but I am staring with MAC and I am a C# programmer and I am thinking in using Xamarin Studio for MAC to create C# apps. Is it a good option or Should I make Objetive-C apps?
Thanks for your help 
Alejandro

Comment: Xamarin at all is very great framework and as you C# developer it will be more easy and faster for you to develop MAC app with it, but I don't think that it's a good question to place it on stackoverflow because it doesn't have direct answer, diff users will provide you diff opinions and you will never receive one correct answer

Comment: This is question, which haven't clear and simple answer. It's person-opinion based.

Comment: The phrasing of the question could be improved to be more objective. In short though, yes, Xamarin Studio is a capable C# IDE

Comment: I use Xamarin and it is a great tool. However, keep in mind that it is not free (but quite cheap if you are in a small team). C# might be easier to start with than objective C because it's a million times safer, but if you have experience with dynamic programming I'd give objective C a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by

> to create C# apps

to create iOS apps with C# then yes Xamarin Studio is an option, if you already know C# then it would be a good option for you. You can write the code in C# in Xamarin and export it for iOS, Android, Mac. If you plan on creating them exclusivly for iOS or Mac then I would say that you should code them in Objective-C.

Comment: you are right ! Sorry for my little English...... Thanks for the info !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are a C# developer is the better for you.
also Xamarin Studio is a great framework and you can develop a really good apps because you can use the native resources from device, for example gps, camera, Bluetooth and more.